# Policy per user in Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm starting to play with Vault from HashiCorp. What I've done is to create a server with file storage and userpassword authentication.

Why I'm trying to accomplish is to setup a policy in a way that every user can have it's own space to be able to create there their own secrets, and then a common team area for shared secrets.

Is it possible to do that without having to create a specific policy at the moment of creation of the user?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As of version 0.10 there isn't any kind of dynamic policy language like this. Vault policies are much like Terraform where they are extremely declarative.

Some people have [talked about](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/1508#issuecomment-225145644) adding a second templating language on top of HCL/your vault policies that would let you insert those kinds of username values, then apply the policy for each user.

Though there is an issue where some of the Vault maintainers have talked about adding support some kind of better policy language features in the future either in Vault or through a new version of their templating language HCL.